# Google Chrome won't open even after reinstall

Tags: ubuntu, apt, chrome

All of a sudden, Google Chrome stopped working and won't open anymore on my Ubuntu 18.04 Server (which I can't restart). Even after remove and reinstall *google-chrome-stable*, it still gives the same error:

- `[1553930:1553930:0316/233920.682604:Error:edid_parser.cc(102)] Too short EDID data: manufacturer id`
- `[1553964:1553964:0316/233920.967066:Error:viz_main_impl.cc(161) Exiting GPU process due to errors during initialization`

Greatly appreciate your help.

Comment: After an update on Ubuntu 16.04 I'm getting the same problem. chromium-browser fails to start, even after reboot. Have you managed to resolve it yet?

Answer (score 1):

Im running the same problem using Kali Linux in virtual environment. 
The error `Error:edid_parser.cc(102)] Too short EDID data` is related to all chromium based apps such as Chromium browser itself, Google Chrome, VS Code, Atom Code Editor, Opera Browser and so on.

This is not an official solution but maybe can throw your error away in the time being. Supposing you want to lauch google chrome you can try this: `google-chrome --disable-gpu`

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but it doesn't solve the problem. Maybe I shall try to reboot the system, sometimes this simple trick can solve many problems. Thanks again. Have a wonderful day.

Comment: Wow this is really annoying. Chromium has finally stopped working on my Ubuntu 16.04. It's always been pretty unreliable tbh, with regular hangs and crashes. This time a reboot has not fixed it. I'm now using Firefox, which is sooo slow. Hopefully this Chromium problem will get fixed.